# How can I set align a uibutton to the right programmatically?

Tags: ios, layout, uibutton, cgrect

Just like the image shown. How can I align a button to the right? **CGRectMake** seems only create frame based on the float x, y which origin from the left top corner. Thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: want you set text from right side or what ?

Comment: If you want to set your button in the right end of the super view then set x origin of your button relative to the width of your superview...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The x origin depend of the width of the superview (in my example self.view)

```
#define RIGHT_MARGIN 20

myButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - myButton.frame.size.width - RIGHT_MARGIN, yValue, myButton.frame.size.width, myButton.frame.size.height)
```

Comment: Note however that if you are using Autolayout (and you should if you only support iOS6+) manipulating the frame directly is not recommended.

Answer (score 4):

For generic `UIButtonTypeCustom`:

```
yourbutton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight;
```

---

`yourbutton.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;` only works if you do have a `titleLabel`.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to set text to the right alignment the try this code.

```
 yourbutton.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
```

If you set tmage then see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116114/uibutton-title-and-image-alignment-query) answer