# How to change image of UIImageView that is inside a UIButton programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, uibutton

I created a UIButton with UIImageView and UILabel by the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116114/uibutton-title-and-image-alignment-query/1116139?noredirect=1#comment49224486_1116139) question and answer by Tim and now I want change the image of the UIImageView on the button click event.
I tried `[sender.imageView setImage:image]` but it not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can:

1 - keep a reference to the UIImageView inside the UIButton on your viewController

2 - Subclass the UIButton and add the UIImageView yourself.

3 - When adding the UIImageView, add a tag into it (view.tag) and when getting the view from the sender, you can just

```
UIView *view = (UIView *)sender;
UIImageView *imageView = [view viewWithTag:123];
//do what you must with the imageView.
```

The tag can be any number.

*Edit*

this is how you should set the tag on the UIImageView, and Not on the UIButton. I copied this code from Tim's answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116114/uibutton-title-and-image-alignment-query/1116139?noredirect=1#comment49224486_1116139):

```
// Create the button
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

// Now load the image and create the image view
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(/*frame*/)];
[imageView setImage:image];

// Create the label and set its text
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(/*frame*/)];
[label setText:@"Your title"];

// Set a tag on the UIImageView so you can get it later
imageView.tag = 123;

// Put it all together
[button addSubview:label];
[button addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: No I don't want to change the image of button but the UIImageView inside that button, have you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116114/uibutton-title-and-image-alignment-query/1116139?noredirect=1#comment49224486_1116139 question and Tim's answer ??

Comment: here 123 is the same tag that set earlier or it is new ?

Comment: It must be the same tag you set earlier. I used "123" as an example.
If you set 700 before, you need to use 700 here, for example.

Comment: application crash at `UIImageView *imageView = [button viewWithTag:123];` Incompatible pointer UIImageView with type UIView

Comment: are you using 123 as the tag when setting the view? That error means that the view being fetched is not a UIImageView

Comment: No I am not using tag 123 but I did replace the 123 with the real tag value, button is not a UIImage type it is UIButton type but I added a subview to that button which was a UIImage type and I want to change image of that UIImage

Comment: Well, UIImage != UIImageView. I edited the answer to be more generic. You cannot add UIImage as a subview, you must add UIImageView which also contains an UIImage. I just tested this and it is working.

Comment: you did't understand I can't set any tag on UIImageView the tag which I have is for  UIButton

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79444/discussion-between-erakk-and-varun-naharia).